# How do I move a SKSpriteNode up and down around its starting value in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm currently working on a game, where there's a SKSpriteNode. I want, that this node's location moves up and down all the time. At the beginning, it should have the y value e.g. 500 . Then it should move 200 px down (500+200=700) and then it should move 400 up (700-400=300) so it creates like a up and down, which travels between 500+200 and 500-200 all the time. I hope I explained it understandable. First, how do I get this effect and second, where do I enter it? Should I use a custom func? I'm programming with swift (newbie to swift)

Comment: I would look into sine waves if I was you and then perhaps use a custom `SKAction` for the implementation.

Comment: This video might help with the general idea. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e2qHv0qlC_g

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sine Wave Motion In SpriteKit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940495/sine-wave-motion-in-spritekit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've written a some sample code which you can adapt for your purposes:

**Firstly,** you need π for the oscillation calculations:

```
// Defined at global scope.
let π = CGFloat(M_PI)
```

**Secondly,** extend `SKAction` so you can easily create actions that will oscillate the node in question:

```
extension SKAction {

    // amplitude  - the amount the height will vary by, set this to 200 in your case.
    // timePeriod - the time it takes for one complete cycle
    // midPoint   - the point around which the oscillation occurs.

    static func oscillation(amplitude a: CGFloat, timePeriod t: Double, midPoint: CGPoint) -> SKAction {
        let action = SKAction.customActionWithDuration(t) { node, currentTime in
            let displacement = a * sin(2 * π * currentTime / CGFloat(t))
            node.position.y = midPoint.y + displacement
        }

        return action
    }
}
```

The `displacement` above comes from the Simple Harmonic Motion equation for displacement. See [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/shm.html#c1) for more information (their's is a rearranged a little, but it's the same equation).

**Thirdly,** putting all that together, in the `SKScene`:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    let node = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.greenColor(), 
                             size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    node.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
    self.addChild(node)

    let oscillate = SKAction.oscillation(amplitude: 200, 
                                        timePeriod: 1,
                                          midPoint: node.position)
    node.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(oscillate))
}
```

If you needed to oscillate the node in the x-axis too I'd recommend adding an `angle` argument to the `oscillate` method and using `sin` and `cos` to determine how much the node should oscillate in each axis.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! Just to make sure it works, will I still be able to recognize collision between my node and other nodes with this method?

Comment: I assume so because it's just using  `SKAction`s, however I haven't tested it under those circumstances myself. Glad to know I could help though! :)